# How to enable my ribbon custom action only when 1 or more list items are selected?

Tags: ribbon, custom-actions

I created a custom action in the ribbon by VS. I see the button always. Also when no list items are selected. How can I enable the button only when 1 or more listitems are selected?

This is my current custom action code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="85691508-c076-4f43-93d4-96b4d5253a09.RibbonCustomAction1"
                RegistrationType="ContentType"
                RegistrationId="0x0101000ACB09B019144AB4A7A9EDD1CCCC4ED3"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
                Sequence="10001"
                Rights="AddListItems"
                Title="Invoke &apos;RibbonCustomAction1&apos; action">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <!-- 
      Update the UI definitions below with the controls and the command actions
      that you want to enable for the custom action.
      -->
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.RibbonCustomAction1Button"
                  Alt="Archive"
                  Sequence="100"
                  Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                  LabelText="Archive"
                  TemplateAlias="o1"
                  Image32by32="_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png"
                  Image16by16="_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                          CommandAction="javascript:alert(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().length);" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension >
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution in 1 line: `EnabledScript="javascript:SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().length > 0;"`

Comment: To complete the answer: `EnabledScript` is an attribute of   `CommandUIHandler`, just like `CommandAction`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `EnabledScript` property in `CommandUIHandler`. Example:

```
 EnabledScript="javascript:
function enableButton() {
    var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
    var ci = CountDictionary(items);
    if (ci > 0) {
        return true;
    }
}
enableButton();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code - I am able to check if any items are selected or not by attaching a click handler to the class `.s4-itm-cbx` (SP 2013)

```
$(".s4-itm-cbx").click(function(){

//console.log(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().length);
if(!SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().length)
{
 //code to enable/disable ribbon button


 $(".ms-cui-tabBody li:nth-child(5)  .ms-cui-row:nth-child(2)").css({display:'none'})
    }




})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your commandUIHandler has to look like the following

```
<CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
      EnabledScript="javascript:
        function enableButton() {
            var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
            var ci = CountDictionary(items);
            if (ci > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        enableButton();"
       CommandAction="javascript:alert(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().length);" />
  </CommandUIHandlers>
```